In CMake does include_directories apply to all targets added with add_subdirectory
It says that "include_directories" applies to all targets in that CMake file, but I was wondering if I do:
include_directories(
PATH1
PATH2
)

add_subdirectory(SOME_SUB_DIRECTORY)

And then in the subdirectory CMakeLists.txt I have a target, like add_library, do the include_directories from the parent apply to all targets downstream?

Yes, all targets created in SOME_SUB_DIRECTORY will have PATH1 and PATH2 among their include directories. But ... Why do not simply check that instead of asking?

@Tsyvarev It didn't inherit it, I'm still trying to figure out what's happening.

What do you mean by "inherit it"? Do you mean that you call add_library(my_lib) under SOME_SUB_DIRECTORY directory, then call add_library(other_lib) somewhere else and call target_link_libraries(other_lib PUBLIC my_lib)? And do you wonder whether PATH1 is added as include directory to target other_lib? Your question about "targets downsteam" is quite vague. Moreover, the question in the title tells nothing about "inheriting". Please, make the whole question post to clearly describe your problem. You could also add more code for demonstrate your scenario.

@Tsyvarev Yes, that's exactly what I mean. And the answer seems to be "No, it doesn't inherit".
